# How to copy string char by char in c?

Tags: c

I have a chunk of memory I'm declaring on the heap.

```
char *str;
str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

I have a const string.

```
const char *name = "chase";
```

Because `*name` is shorter than `10` I need to fill `str` with `chase` plus 5 spaces.

I've tried to loop and set `str[i] = name[i]` but there's something I'm not matching up because I cannot assign spaces to the additional chars. This was where I was going, just trying to fill `str` with all spaces to get started

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    strcpy(str[i], ' ');
    printf("char: %c\n", str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Show some actual code.

Comment: `strcpy()` is for you.

Comment: Going by what you write, you should fill str with the name, *four* spaces and terminating `'\0'` byte. Or if you want 10 actual chars, then make the array length 11, so you have room for the `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

As the others pointed out, you need

```
 //malloc casting is (arguably) bad
 str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);
```

and then, just do

```
 snprintf(str, 11, "%10s", name);
```

Using `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` will prevent overflow, and `%10s`will pad your resulting string as you want.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

Answer (score 0):

If you want `str` to have 10 characters and still be a C-string, you need to `'\0'` terminate it.  You can do this by `malloc`ing `str` to a length of 11:

```
str = malloc(11);
```

Note there's no need to cast the return pointer of `malloc`.  Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so there's no need to multiply that by the number of `char`s that you want.

After you've `malloc` as much memory as you need you can use `memset` to set all the `char`s to `' '` (the space character) except the last element.  The last element needs to be `'\0'`:

```
memset(str, ' ', 10);
str[10] = '\0';
```

Now, use `memcpy` to copy your `const` C-string to `str`:

```
memcpy(str, name, strlen(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

easy to use snprintf like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *str;
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10+1);//+1 for '\0'
    const char *name = "chase";

    snprintf(str, 11, "%-*s", 10, name);//11 is out buffer size
    printf(" 1234567890\n");
    printf("<%s>\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```